# Access Java Web Service and get response

Tags: java, xml, web-services, wsdl

I am doing a project which has to access to a given web service and send data to requested parameters and get the response from service. Currently I do something which I found from a forum and it parse the data to service, but unable to get the response since its giving an error. 
My sample code is below.

```
package webserviceexample;
import javax.xml.soap.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
public class aaaa {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {           
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
         String url = "https://vlmt.XXX.lk:0111/VendorRecharge/services/RechargeVendorService/wsdl/";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);
        printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);
        //soapConnection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
    String serverURI = "http://vendor.XXX.ZZZ.com/";

    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("wsdl", serverURI);

    SOAPBody soapBody1 = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement soapBodyElemX = soapBody1.addChildElement("performRecharge", "wsdl");

    SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElemX.addChildElement("storeId", "wsdl");
    soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("LA19BNPX");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElemX.addChildElement("password", "wsdl");
    soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("thilanka@456A");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem3 = soapBodyElemX.addChildElement("mobileNo", "wsdl");
    soapBodyElem3.addTextNode("751238456");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem4 = soapBodyElemX.addChildElement("Amount", "wsdl");
    soapBodyElem4.addTextNode("12");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem5 = soapBodyElemX.addChildElement("vendorTransactionId", "wsdl");
    soapBodyElem5.addTextNode("15");

    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("performRecharge", serverURI + "performRecharge");
    System.out.println("");
    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
    System.out.println();
    return soapMessage;
}

private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
    System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
}
```

}

The error I am getting is:

**Request SOAP Message**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-    ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   
  xmlns:wsdl="http://vendor.virtualization.ibm.com/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <wsdl:performRecharge>
      <wsdl:storeId>LA19BNPX</wsdl:storeId> 
      <wsdl:password>thilanka@456A</wsdl:password>
      <wsdl:mobileNo>751238456</wsdl:mobileNo>
      <wsdl:Amount>12</wsdl:Amount> 
    <wsdl:vendorTransactionId>15</wsdl:vendorTransactionId>
   </wsdl:performRecharge>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Response (error)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope   
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode>   
      <faultstring>javax.xml.rpc.JAXRPCException: WSWS3122E: Error: Could not find service services/RechargeVendorService/wsdl/ referenced in URI /VendorRecharge/services/RechargeVendorService/wsdl/</faultstring>
   </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have to call the "performRecharge" in the web service. Please help me.
A summary of the web service is below.

Please help me overcome this. It's very important.
Thank you.

WSDL FILE

Comment: Start by not shouting at us.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that this is the correct service URL.

Seems like you specified the wsdl location and not registered service url. Set the request url specified in the wsdl file for the service.

```
String url = "https://vlmt.XXX.lk:0111/VendorRecharge/services/RechargeVendorService/wsdl/";
```

See the location tag in your wsdl

```
<service name="Hello_Service">
      <documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</documentation>
      <port binding="tns:Hello_Binding" name="Hello_Port">
         <soap:address
            location="**http://www.examples.com/SayHello/**">
      </port>
   </service>
```

Comment: After I place the url in the browser I can get the performRecharge in their.

Comment: if url is correct , try using http instead of https and see if it works.

Comment: I tried dude,but its giving huge exception

"Feb 20, 2014 9:32:22 AM com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection post
SEVERE: SAAJ0009: Message send failed
Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Message send failed"

Comment: Which version of WAS are you using ?

Comment: how to know that? the web service written by out sider and I have to access it. Please explain me what is WAS version. Thank you

Comment: Updated in the Question Dude. I just want to call to RechargeRequestDTO.Please Help

Comment: I dont see any WSDL file content, just paste the content here.

Comment: Finally I did it dude.thank for your great help. Really appreciate.